# Update database with datatable data with a where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable

I am building a program that will update an early voted column in my data base with a 1 if the voter early voted. I need a way that users can upload a CSV’s and match the id column of that CSV to the id of the voter in my database, and then update his early voted status. Since the CSV’s will be coming from users I will not know the amount of columns in the CSV’s, some may have 2 columns some may have 10, but all will have an id column that will match the id of a voter in my database.  I have the code that uploads the CSV and insert it into the datatable, but I need help with the logic for the insert into the database. I was thinking something like this, but don’t know the correct way to handle it.

```
 UPDATE personal SET earlyVoted = 1 where personal.id = datatable.id
```

This is the code I have for the datatable

```
string target = Server.MapPath("~/Upload");
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(target, FileUpload1.FileName));
        string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Text;", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(target + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        string cmdString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(target + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdString, connString);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE (SELECT personal.earlyvoted 
          FROM personal
             , datatable 
         WHERE personal.id = datatable.id) 
   SET earlyvoted = 1;
```

You'll need primary key on id in each table.